# gRPC load balancer/name resolver example?

Tags: go, grpc

Does anybody have working gRPC load balancer/name resolver example in go? Nothing fancy just round robin over list of predefined addresses.

UPDATE:
What i mean is that gRPC has dial option WithBalancer, which is used like

```
    var opts []grpc.DialOption
    b := grpc.RoundRobin(r) //r - name resolver
    opts = append(opts, grpc.WithBalancer(b))
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("", opts...)
```

Is there any example of how to implement name resolver to work with this code?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you are looking for. Is it a library to take a request and forward it to a pool of targets, or a full-fledged load balancer?

Comment: I updated my original post

Comment: I haven't try new balancer API on my own (because we have our own balancer implementation)... but I think that unit-tests may inspire you :

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/balancer/roundrobin/roundrobin_test.go#L125

Comment: Actually reading through test was surpsisingly simple, and really helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/wothing/wonaming

Wonaming is a simple grpc-go balancer & naming implementation, supporting etcd and Consul as the service register/discovery backend. Wonaming also supports self-register to etcd/consul.